# Digest Authentication With Apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, web-services, authentication, cxf

I'm trying to make a web service call with Java and Apache's cxf library, and of course, if possible, this should happen with digest authentication, basic as fallback if the server doesn't support digest.

I have the following code, creating a service port from the WSDL, creating a HTTPConduit, which is able to handle the authentication negotiation, and setting the desired authorization type "Digest".

```
MyService myService = new MyService("wsdl-url");
MyServicePort myServicePort = myService.getMyServicePort();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(myServicePort);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
authPolicy.setAuthorizationType("Digest");
authPolicy.setUserName("user");
authPolicy.setPassword("myPassword");
http.setAuthorization(authPolicy);

myServicePort.doSomething();
```

Now this works perfectly fine if the server responds with accepting digest authentication only, thus with the header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="...", nonce="...", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"\r\n
```

But there is another server (the servers are actually cameras)  which responds by offering both authentication methods, basic and digest:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="...", nonce="...", stale=FALSE, qop="auth"\r\n
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="..."\r\n
```

And there it will fail, because the retransmission is not sent. I guess cxf just picks one of the two methods, which by chance is basic, but does not find an authorization policy with the basic method, and therefore it fails.

Here is some of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://192.168.x.x/vapix/services
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1600) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1607) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1551) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
```

Does anybody know if this is a bug by cxf? Or is there a workaround for that? My only idea would be to write my own HttpAuthSupplier, but this might be a bit delicate.

Thanks,
Silvan

Comment: did you got any solutions