# Adding digest authentication to SOAP request

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, digest-authentication

I'm trying to add digest authentication (username and password) to my SOAP request which uses org.apache.cxf (3.3.2) for classes generation. I've tried to append the username and password using the [BindingProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html) with no success:

```
MyServiceGeneratedClass soapClient = new MyServiceGeneratedClass();
MyServicePort port = soapClient.getMyServicePort();
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "mySecretUsername");
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mySecretPassword");
```

The generated SOAP request does not contain the user and password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Similiar post is about [Digest Authentication With Apache CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932164/digest-authentication-with-apache-cxf)

Maybe that solution might work for you as well :

```
MyService myService = new MyService("wsdl-url");
MyServicePort myServicePort = myService.getMyServicePort();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(myServicePort);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
authPolicy.setAuthorizationType("Digest");
authPolicy.setUserName("user");
authPolicy.setPassword("myPassword");
http.setAuthorization(authPolicy);

myServicePort.doSomething();
```

Comment: Hi, my client does not export a "getConduit()" =(

Comment: Maybe helps, but here is a documentation about HTTPConduitConfigurer, if you could configure your own, please check "How to use HTTPConduitConfigurer?"

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-HowtouseHTTPConduitConfigurer?

Comment: I added cxf-rt-frontend-simple and cxf-rt-transports-http dependencies to my project to be able to use Client and ClientProxy but now I'm getting a  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy when trying to Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(myServicePort);

Comment: I switch cxf-rt-frontend-simple to cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws and there is not ClassCastException, but still does not work.

I added cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws and cxf-rt-transports-http dependencies to my project to be able to use Client and ClientProxy but the Authorization is not being added to the request structure.